# How do I find how much money is stored on all deployed instances of a contract?

Tags: contract-deployment, etherscan

I am reviewing a certain contract, and would like to gauge how much money is stored on all deployed instances of this contract.

Someone told me I can deploy a new instances of the contract to mainnet, then view it on Etherscan and look for "similar or identiacal contracts" and just tally the results.

Would this work? If so, is [this](https://medium.com/mercuryprotocol/dev-highlights-of-this-week-cb33e58c745f) the easiest way to deploy a contract? Can I use [remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) for this deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach would work - the easiest way to deploy the contract, given you already have the code, would be to just use Remix. You can also go to the existing contract on etherscan.io and search for similar contracts (go to the code tab, then select "Find Similar Contracts") so you may not need to deploy your own version if there is already a copy on the blockchain.

Comment: This doesn't currently work for me: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50964/how-do-i-change-the-sensitivity-level-of-etherscan-similar-contract-search

Comment: Yep - it only allows exact matching at the moment it seem. Is your use-case not for an exact match?

Comment: No, I need a fuzzy search.

Comment: AFAICT etherscan.io no longer supports this unfortunately.